# Ошибка безопасности в WordPress: Error code 15 This request was blocked by the security rules

Tags: html, wordpress

Хочу на свой сайт добавить видео с одного сервиса, но мне выдает следующие ошибки:

```
hqq.tv - Access Denied<br>
Error code 15<br>
This request was blocked by the security rules<br>
```

Сайт на *WP 4.2.2*. Добавить хочу следующий код:

```
<iframe src="http://hqq.tv/player/embed_player.php?vid=227235227231227238239228224207244211&autoplay=no" height="450" width="720" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

Как добавить нужный мне сайт в доверенную зону, чтобы видео с этих доменов добавлялись без проблем?

Comment: А кто и куда выдает это сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: Я же написал WP 4.2.2. (wordPress версия 4.2.2)

Comment: Имелось в виду куда именно ошибка выводится (лог веб сервера, консоль браузера, содержимое страницы....)?

Comment: когда я добавляю видео и нажимаю просмотр с сайта до того как на жать на просмотр самого виде все нормально. Но когда нажимаю смотреть  сразу выкидывает эту ошибку.